# KnockoutJS and Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am creating a simple weight and balance application for flying using KnockoutJS.  This involves calculating the arm `(moment / weight)` and the moment `(weight * arm)`.  As you can see, arm is dependent on moment, and vice-versa.  The issue I'm having is when a user updates either the moment or arm, I get an infinite loop, which I need to break.

Here's my code:

```
function weightAndBalance(_arm)
{
    var self = this;
    this.weight = ko.observable(0);
    this.arm = ko.computed(function()
    {
        if(parseFloat(self.weight()) == 0)
        {
            return _arm;
        }

        console.log("Arm: " + parseFloat(self.moment()) / parseFloat(self.weight()));
        return parseFloat(self.moment()) / parseFloat(self.weight());
    });
    this.moment = ko.computed(function()
    {
        console.log("Moment: " + parseFloat(self.weight()) * parseFloat(self.arm()));
        return parseFloat(self.weight()) * parseFloat(self.arm());
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new weightAndBalance(80.1));
```

And my markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Arm</th>
        <th>Moment</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Front Passengers</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: weight" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: arm" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: moment" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The user should enter a weight, and the moment field should be populated.  In the case that the moment field is manually entered, the arm should be automatically recalculated.

I've prepared a live demo in [Fiddle form](http://jsfiddle.net/JarVS/2/).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean - I don't see any calculations in that fiddle?

Comment: Please include any relevant code in the question.

Comment: knockout should handle this...

Comment: I looked at that example, and I believe their problem is slightly different than mine.  In his, you can only edit 2 of the fields, whereas mine you can edit all 3.  I believe this changes the logic behind my computed observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest making some "private" observables, exposed by computed observables that are also writable.

With *three* observables depending on eachother, the additional risk for an infinite loop can be prevented by deciding which variable remains "fixed" when one changes.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avpQS/) I've done that as follows:

- If **weight** changes, the **moment** is updated and **arm** remains fixed.
- If **moment** changes, the **arm** is updated and **weight** remains fixed.
- If **arm** changes, the **moment** is updated and **weight** remains fixed.

The "private" observables look like this:

```
_weight = ko.observable(parseFloat(initialWeight) || 0);
_arm = ko.observable(parseFloat(initialArm) || 0);
_moment = ko.observable(_weight() * _arm());
```

Then the three computed observables look like this:

```
self.weight = ko.computed({
    write: function (val) {
        _weight(parseFloat(val));
        _moment(_arm() * _weight());
    },
    read: _weight
});

self.arm = ko.computed({
    write: function (val) {
        _arm(parseFloat(val));
        _moment(_arm() * _weight());
    },
    read: _arm
});

self.moment = ko.computed({
    write: function(val) {
        _moment(parseFloat(val));
        _arm(_moment() / _weight());
    },
    read: _moment
});
```

Now you can update any one of the three observables safely. Only one of the other observables will change, preventing circularity problems.

Comment: That works perfectly!  I think it's also the cleanest solution.  Thanks @Jeroen!

Comment: Also, in case anyone wants to see the final product, here's my working example of an online aircraft weight and balance app:  http://jsfiddle.net/JarVS/17/

Answer (score 1):

You only defined the read method on your computeds.
If you want get the typed info you need to add write method.

I create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JarVS/6/) in which I create 3 regular observables and 2  methods to process the data. I think it's simpler to do so and it's infinite loop free.

```
this.weight = ko.observable(0);
this.arm = ko.observable(0);
this.moment = ko.observable(0);

this.computeArm = function () {

    if (parseFloat(self.weight()) == 0) {
        return _arm;
    }

    console.log("Arm: " + parseFloat(self.moment()) / parseFloat(self.weight()));
    self.arm( parseFloat(self.moment()) / parseFloat(self.weight()));
}


this.computeMoment = function () {
    console.log("Moment: " + parseFloat(self.weight()) * parseFloat(self.arm()));
    self.moment( parseFloat(self.weight()) * parseFloat(self.arm()));
};
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You were only missing one item:  self.weight needed to also subscribe to computeMoment:  http://jsfiddle.net/JarVS/9/.  I think it's working now, thanks!